# Questions system based on player's answer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to create a simple game on Unity where, after the game shows a question to the player, they have to choose between "yes" or "no" as answer.
Based on what they choose, the question had to change.

I made a code that is surely messy and also it doesn't completely work.
It work for the first "yes" answer and "no" answer but then it just don't keep work.

Any help on how to resolve and how to make it a bit more optimised?
Thanks in advise to all!

```
public class questionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshPro questionText;
    public TextMeshPro positiveText;
    public TextMeshPro negativeText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI positiveTextIndex;
    public TextMeshProUGUI negativeTextIndex;

    public string[] lines;
    public string[] positiveLines;
    public string[] negativeLines;


    public float textsSpeed;

    bool hasAnswered = false;
    bool positiveAnswer;

    private int index;
    private int positiveIndex;
    private int negativeIndex;
    private void Start()
    {
        questionText.text = string.Empty;
        startDialogue();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        checkAnswer();

        if(positiveText.text == "fine")
        {
            Destroy(questionText);
        }
        else if(negativeText.text == "fine")
        {
            Destroy(questionText);
        }

        positiveTextIndex.text = positiveIndex.ToString();
        negativeTextIndex.text = negativeIndex.ToString();
    }


    void startDialogue()
    {
        index = 0;
        StartCoroutine(typeLine());
    }

    IEnumerator typeLine()
    {
        
        if (positiveAnswer == true && hasAnswered == true)
        {
            foreach (char c in positiveLines[index].ToCharArray())
            {
                questionText.text += c;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(textsSpeed);
            }
        }
        else if(positiveAnswer == false && hasAnswered == true)
        {

            foreach (char c in negativeLines[index].ToCharArray())
            {
                questionText.text += c;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(textsSpeed);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (char c in lines[index].ToCharArray())
            {
                questionText.text += c;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(textsSpeed);
            }
        }

       
    }
    void checkAnswer()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            positiveAnswer = true;
            chooseLine();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            positiveAnswer = false;
            chooseLine();
        }
    }
    void chooseLine()
    { 
        if (positiveAnswer == true)
        {
            positiveIndex++;
            hasAnswered = true;
            nextLine();
        }
        else if(positiveAnswer== false)
        {
            negativeIndex++;
            hasAnswered = true;
            nextLine();
        }

    }
    void nextLine()
    {
        questionText.text = string.Empty;
        StartCoroutine(typeLine()); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the player only has two fixed choices (yes or no), I would suggest using two buttons instead of two text inputs and a third one to resign.  If you do not want to use buttons but rather typed input I would suggest taking a look into the InputActionMap instead of using the method you used. If you do not want to display the amount of times yes or no was answered, you can delete those TMP_Texts. To store the questions I would suggest using a binary tree.

```
public class QuestionScript1 : MonoBehaviour{
  public TMP_Text question;
  public TMP_Text positiveTextIndex;
  public TMP_Text negativeTextIndex;

  public string[] positiveLines;
  public string[] negativeLines;

  public float textsSpeed;

  private int positiveIndex = 0;
  private int negativeIndex = 0;
  private bool resigned = false;

  void Start() {
    positiveTextIndex.text = "0";
    negativeTextIndex.text = "0";
    StartCoroutine(typeLine(true, true));
  }

  private IEnumerator typeLine(bool answer, bool automated) {
    if (!resigned) {
      question.text = null;
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(textsSpeed);
      if (automated) {
        question.text = "0";
      } else if (answer) {
        question.text = positiveLines[positiveIndex+negativeIndex]; //or wathever
      } else {
        question.text = negativeLines[negativeIndex+negativeIndex]; //or wathever
      }
    }
  }


  public void answerIsYes() { //a button calls it or you use an InputActionMap
    positiveIndex++;
    positiveTextIndex.text = positiveIndex.ToString();
    StartCoroutine(typeLine(true, false));
  }

  public void answerIsNo() { //a button calls it or you use an InputActionMap
    negativeIndex++;
    negativeTextIndex.text = negativeIndex.ToString();
    StartCoroutine(typeLine(false, false));
  }

  public void resign() { //a button calls it or you use an InputActionMap
    question.text = null;
    resigned = true;
    //whatever you want it to do
  }
}
```

I hope that helps.